# Allow FTP via Internet Explorer in IIS7?

Tags: internet-explorer, iis-7, ftp

I have an FTP account created and it works fine with an FTP client but won't work with IE.  If I remember correctly IIS6 let you do this with no problems, is there a rule or setting I am missing?

I currently have 1 Allow rule for a specific user and 1 deny rule for all Anonymous users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this post [Out Of Band FTP 7 shows "Operation timed out"](http://blogs.msdn.com/vivekkum/archive/2008/09/10/out-of-band-ftp-7-shows-operation-timed-out.aspx).. verify FTP and Firewall settings are good.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the client operating system/internet explorer version. You can use My Computer/Computer. IE removed this functionality for 7.0.